# How to update a dependency in package-lock.json

Tags: security, github, dependencies, package-lock.json

I've received for the first time a notification from GitHub about a potential security issue (label: high-severity) with some of my project's dependencies. Here's the sample message:

> url-parse vulnerability found in package-lock.json

And this is the proposed solution:

> Upgrade url-parse to version 1.4.3 or later. For example:

```
"dependencies": {
  "url-parse": ">=1.4.3"
}
```

or…

```
"devDependencies": {
  "url-parse": ">=1.4.3"
}
```

Now, what I did was to simply check for any outdated packages by running `npm outdated -g --depth=0` in my terminal as per the [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/updating-global-packages) and execute the `npm -g update` command (I also tried targeting the dependency itself with `npm update url-parse`). A few packages were successfully updated, but it didn't seem to find the package causing the issue. Am I supposed to update it manually by adding the suggested line of code: `"url-parse": ">=1.4.3"`?

And finally, how much should I be concerned with such alerts?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to update it is probably to go into the `package-lock.json` file as you suggested and modifying the old `"version": "#.#.#"` to be `"version": ">=1.4.3"` under the `url-parse` JSON object. I'd suggest `COMMAND+F`ing the dependency name (`CONTROL+F` for the W indows users) since the `package-lock.json` file can easily be thousands of lines long, and once you find your dependency, changing the version number to what GitHub deems to be safe from the vulnerability.

I just created a new repo and I got a very similar message for the `ws` dependency, and after updating the version in the `package-lock.json` file manually I received this message after refreshing the GitHub alerts page:

```
No open alerts on ws were found in package-lock.json.
Alerts may have been resolved and deleted by recent pushes to this repository.
```

For reference, here's what it looked like for me before I updated the `ws` dependency:

```
"ws": {
      "version": "1.1.5",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/-/ws-1.1.5.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-o3KqipXNUdS7wpQzBHSe180lBGO60SoK0yVo3CYJgb2MkobuWuBX6dhkYP5ORCLd55y+SaflMOV5fqAB53ux4w==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "options": ">=0.0.5",
        "ultron": "1.0.x"
      }
```

and after:

```
"ws": {
      "version": ">=3.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ws/-/ws-1.1.5.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-o3KqipXNUdS7wpQzBHSe180lBGO60SoK0yVo3CYJgb2MkobuWuBX6dhkYP5ORCLd55y+SaflMOV5fqAB53ux4w==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "options": ">=0.0.5",
        "ultron": "1.0.x"
      }
```

You've probably already figured this out by now, as I see you posted this question almost a year ago, but leaving this here to help anyone in the future who comes across a similar issue.

Comment: "leaving this here to help anyone in the future who comes across a similar issue." That's the spirit!

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but won't this just get overwritten next time someone runs `npm install`?

Comment: I just tried doing a manual update and then running `npm install`, and it does indeed overwrite the manual change

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to edit the lock file by hand, just run:

```
npm install --package-lock-only url-parse
```

it should install latest version of the package and update only lock file

For unknow reason it also update package.json so you need:

```
git checkout package.json
```

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599356/what-does-npm-i-package-lock-only-do) that command only modifies `package-lock.json` without installing. Other than that, it behaves the same as `npm i`. So the fact it modifies package.json is totally expected, and it does not really install anything. No idea why you mention `git checkout`, either.

Answer (score 0):

I tried both the accepted answer and the other answer, and neither worked.

I found this article by Ankur Kaushur, [Updating a package's dependency in package-lock.json](https://ankurkaushal.com/update-dependency-package-lock/)

**Step 1**. Run `npm audit fix` which will update most dependencies.

**Step 2**. If your security audit has found other issues that were not picked up in step 1, you can change the version numbers manually in `package-lock.json` and then run `npm ci` (this will retain your manual change).

If you get an error when running `npm ci` saying that you `package.json` and your lock file are out of sync, you can then run `npm install` and it still won't overwrite your manual change.