# How do I update a single dependency in package-lock.json, without any side effects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, frontend

I am looking to update the following `NPM (v5)` dependency in my application from version `1.0.0` to `1.0.1` without any change to my `package.json` file.

```
"dependencies": {
  "package": "~1.0.0"
},
```

My current package-lock.json file references the dependency as version `1.0.0`, so as expected, running `npm install` installs version `1.0.0` of the package.

The issue lies when running either `npm install package@1.0.1` or `npm update package` where both commands seem to change how the package version reference in `package.json`

Is there a single command I can run to achieve a minor version update to only the `package-lock.json` file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why would you want to do this without updating `package.json` ?

Comment: @mihai We use the tilda character to pick up the latest patch version of our package. I see no reason why we need to change how we reference the package version between development and release branches.

Comment: I think these answers
1-[package versions in package lock.json have a prefix, sometimes its ~ sometimes ^](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70860869/16298287)
2-[updating the version in the package-lock.json file manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58142690/16298287) can help

Answer (score 10):

Run `npm update <package>`.

This will update it to the latest version that satisfies the requirements specified in your `package.json` and reflect the update in the `package-lock.json`.

Answer (score -3):

`package-lock.json` is generated by npm and it's difficult to modify without npm since it contains  package hashes.

If you're only referencing modules using the patch version (`~1.0.0`) I think it's safe to do the following:

- Backup `package.json` and delete it
- Run `npm update package`. This will use `package-lock.json` as a reference and will also update `package-lock.json`
- Restore `package.json`
- Running `npm update package` now will not update `package.json` since `package-lock.json` is the newer version

If you're looking for a one line command:

```
mv package.json package.json.tmp && npm update package && mv package.json.tmp package.json
```

Again, this is safe to do only when dealing with patch versions (`~1.0.0`). If you specify minor (`^1.0.0`) or major (`1.0.0`) versions you may want to update `package.json` directly.