# Cloud function does not upload once googleapis are included

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud functions project and once I include the googleapis to authorize to play developer api I cannot deploy the project anymore. This is the mwe:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as serviceAccountPlay from './service-account.json'; 
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export const realtimeNotificationListener = 
functions.pubsub.topic('billing_information').onPublish(async (data, context) => {
    //With this it does not deploy. Removing this deploys successfully
    const authClient = new google.auth.JWT({
       email: serviceAccountPlay.client_email,
       key: serviceAccountPlay.private_key,
       scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"]
    })
    const playDeveloperApiClient = google.androidpublisher({ 
       version: 'v3',
       auth: authClient}
    );
    const developerNotification = data.json;
    console.log('Received realtime notification: ', developerNotification);
    try {
      const subscription = await playDeveloperApiClient.purchases.subscriptions.get({
          packageName: developerNotification.packageName,
          subscriptionId: developerNotification.subscriptionNotification!.subscriptionId,
          token: developerNotification.subscriptionNotification!.purchaseToken
      });
      console.log('Received purchase information: ', subscription)
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
})
```

I have this line in my package.json dependenies section:  `"googleapis":"^94.0.0"`

I deployed using this command `firebase --debug deploy --only functions:realtimeNotificationListener`

The debug output is not very helpful:

> [2022-02-01T11:57:02.767Z] Error: Failed to update function playSubBilling-realtimeNotificationListener in region us-central1
> at C:\Users-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:38:11
> at runMicrotasks ()
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async Fabricator.updateV1Function (C:\Users-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:255:32)
> at async Fabricator.updateEndpoint (C:\Users-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:136:13)
> at async handle (C:\Users-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\deploy\functions\release\fabricator.js:75:17)

**EDIT**
After installing googleapis in the `/functions` folder I get a whole lot of other errors:

After `npm i googleapis --save` I get:

[image]

After `npm audit fix` I get:

[image]

And after `firebase --debug deploy --only functions:realtimeNotificationListener` I get:

[image]

What do I have to change to get this running again?

**EDIT 2**

Fixed it with
`npm audit fix --force`
and
`npm update`

Comment: I tried deploying your mwe but it returned the error `'playDeveloperApiClient' is declared but its value is never read.`, if I commented that part of code  the function is deployed but fails to initiate `Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code`.  Could you please help me reproduce your issue by providing detailed reproduction steps?

Comment: Sorry I extended the example by the complete code, so now the `playDeveloperApiClient` is used. But you are already further then I am, because I cannot deploy the above function due to the error that I posted. I also tried removing the old function via console so it is not an update but I still cannot deploy. Any idea what could be the cause? If I commentthe authClient and all errors that follow, the bare functions deploys successfully. Only after I add the authClient (googleapis) it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be caused by not installing the dependencies in the correct directory.

When writing a Firebase Function all of its dependencies should be installed in the `/functions` directory.

For your specific situation the `"googleapis":"^94.0.0"` dependency should be added to the `package.json` in the `/functions` directory, not the main  project one. To solve this I recommend going to the `/functions` directory and running the command:

```
npm i googleapis --save
```

The `package-lock.json` should be updated automatically when installing a dependency, but if it doesn't you can  create a new one which will overwrite the old one by running this command :

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

More info about this command can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599356/what-does-npm-i-package-lock-only-do).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. Thank you. I installed it in root. But now I think I have some dependency problems with the project. Please have a look at the edit above where I will add pictures. I am not sure how to fix those

Comment: Fixed it, see update